# how to enable repo with yum-config-manager --enable<repo>

Tags: yum

During the try to install yum-utils, I ran into the problem that there seems to be no enabled repos. How can I enable `yum-config-manager`, when I seem to need him to do so.

```
[root@spectrumscale ~]# yum install yum-utils
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

Answer (score 4):

**To install specific package from specific repo you can use**

```
yum install --enablerepo=name-of-repo name-of-package
```

Say there can be conflict between version, consider example of installing `mariadb 5.5.66`, in my case I got 2 repo `mariadb-5` and `mariadb-10`, suppose if I wish to install from `mariadb-5` repo then I use

```
yum install --disablerepo=mariadb-10  --enablerepo=mariadb-5  MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

**To enable enable specific repo, you can use**

```
yum-config-manager --enable name-of-repo
```

**Here is example on `Centos 7.7`**

```
[root@localhost server-setup]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

[root@localhost server-setup]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * epel: mirror.poliwangi.ac.id
 * extras: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * remi-safe: mirror.innosol.asia
 * updates: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
repo id                                               repo name                                                                                        status
CodeIT/x86_64                                         CodeIT repo                                                                                         369
base/7/x86_64                                         CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                  10,097
epel/x86_64                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                   13,453
extras/7/x86_64                                       CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                   305
ius/x86_64                                            IUS for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                 641
mariadb-10                                            MariaDB                                                                                              94
mariadb-5                                             MariaDB                                                                                              39
remi-safe                                             Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                        3,621
updates/7/x86_64                                      CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                  711
repolist: 29,330
```

**To Disable**

```
[root@localhost server-setup]# yum-config-manager --disable mariadb-5
```

**After Disabling**

```
[root@localhost server-setup]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * epel: mirror.poliwangi.ac.id
 * extras: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * remi-safe: mirror.innosol.asia
 * updates: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
repo id                                               repo name                                                                                        status
CodeIT/x86_64                                         CodeIT repo                                                                                         369
base/7/x86_64                                         CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                  10,097
epel/x86_64                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                   13,453
extras/7/x86_64                                       CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                   305
ius/x86_64                                            IUS for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                                                 641
mariadb-10                                            MariaDB                                                                                              94
remi-safe                                             Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                                        3,621
updates/7/x86_64                                      CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                  711
repolist: 29,291
```

**What it actually does ???**

I got `MariaDB.repo` file at `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, when you use `--enable <repo-name>` or `--disable <repo-name>`, it will change the value of `enabled =` to `0` or `1`, based on this, `yum repolist` will show you repositories.

```
[root@localhost server-setup]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo 
[mariadb-10]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.4.10/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
[mariadb-5]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5.66/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
enabled = 1
```

Comment: `[root@xiaojguan]# yum-config-manager --enable docker-ce-stable/7/x86_64
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror`

Comment: whats exactly the message ? seems package `glibc-langpack-en` missing ? may be `yum reinstall glibc-langpack-en`